# How do I make my SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable respect intrinsicContentSize in previews?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode11, intrinsic-content-size

When I create a view in SwiftUI and render it in an Xcode preview, using `PreviewLayout.sizeThatFits`, the preview adjusts its size according to its content. When I import a UIKIt view using `UIViewRepresentable`, it appears with a full device-size frame.

Is there a way to make SwiftUI respect the `intrinsicContentSize` of `UIView` subclasses?

```
struct Label: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) -> UILabel {
        return UILabel()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) {
        uiView.text = "Some text"
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct Label_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            Label().previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 34):

Add the following to your updateUIView function:

```
uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful. Turns out that it also works when setting the contentHuggingPriorities in `makeUIView` after creating the view. It feels a bit cleaner to me because this needs to be configured only once, not every time the view is updated...

Comment: I added this settings in `func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType`, it works well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can also limit the `UIViewRepresentable` size from the *SwiftUI side*.

For this you can use [`fixedSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()):

```
struct Label_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Label()
            .fixedSize()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

You can also fix the view size in one dimension only:

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 5, SwiftUI 15, the following is a solution that works for a view hierarchy using layout constraints.

The key is to pass the representable a binding that the SwiftUI view uses to set the height of the view. The representable sets the value of the height by asking the system for the minimum size that fits.

This works for both UIViewRepresentable and UIViewControllerRepresentable.

```swift
struct WrappingView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> WrappedViewController {   
        return WrappedViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: WrappedViewController, context: Context) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            height = uiViewController.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        }
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = WrappedViewController
}
```

Then in the SwiftUI view, set the frame height to match the value from the representable.

```swift
struct MixedView: View {
    @State private var wrappedViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WrappingView(height: $wrappedViewHeight)
            .frame(height: wrappedViewHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Sample wrapped view controller for trivial case

```swift
class WrappedViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Testing"
        label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

And in Xcode 15, a preview is as simple as

```swift
#Preview {
    MixedView()
}
```